# Pyinstallerでexe化したexe経由で別のプログラムファイルを起動すると「コンソールウインドウホスト」という不要なウインドウが表示される

Tags: python, c++, windows

Python経由で、exeファイルを作成するプログラムを作成しました。
WinPython環境で、以下のスクリプトを実行しても不要なウインドウは表示されませんでした。

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

exePath = ""

#PythonまたはPyinstallerでexe化したファイルの実行ファイルのパスを元に、同階層のC++ベースのexeファイルを探す
ExecutionPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
exePath = os.path.join(ExecutionPath,"ExpressionApp", 'ExpressionApp.exe')

subprocess.Popen([exePath],shell=False)
```

しかし、上記のプログラムをPyinstallerを使用してexe化すると、「コンソールウインドウホスト」という不要な黒いウインドウが表示されてしまいます。
使用したPyinstallerコマンドは以下の通りです。

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller test.py --onefile --noconsole
```

`--noconsole`オプションを使用しているので、Python自体のコンソールは表示されないのですが、呼び出し先のexeファイルの起動時にコンソールウインドウホストが表示されているようです。

Pythonから呼び出しに使用しているexeファイルは次のURLにあるものです。
こちらのコードはC++で書かれています。
https://github.com/NVIDIA/MAXINE-AR-SDK/tree/master/samples/ExpressionApp

C++側の問題でコンソールウインドウホストが表示されてしまうのか、それともPython側のPyinstallerなどの仕様でコンソールウインドウホストが表示されてしまうのか分かりません。
このウインドウを消す方法はあるのでしょうか？

タスクマネージャーに表示されたコンソールウインドウホストの画像です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: リンク先を見るとExpressionApp.exe自身がUI(ExpressionAppUI.cpp/hというソース)を持っていたりヘルプ情報をコンソールに表示したりするようですし、ExpressionApp.exeをマウスでダブルクリックすると(必要なdllなどのPATHが設定されていないので)一瞬だけコマンドプロンプト画面が出てプログラムは終了します。この際PyInstallerやPythonスクリプトは関係無いのでは？ 何か工夫するとしたら、subprocess.Popen()のstdin,stdout,stderrをPIPEにするとか試してみてはどうでしょう？ その場合Pythonスクリプトの方はExpressionApp.exeが終了するまで待ち状態にしてPIPEが終了しないようにする必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: Popenの引数を「shell=True」にして、「--noconsole」を使用してexeファイルを作ってみてください。pyinstallerは使っていないのですが、似たような環境を作って試したら、コンソールが出なくなりました。「shell=True」だとかえってだめなんじゃないかと思っていたので意外なのですが。

Comment: ExpressionApp.exeは、run.batをクリックすることで起動します。不思議なことですが、「shell=True」にしたら確かにコンソールが消えました。回答頂けたらチェックします、ありがとうございます。。